# How to build Fake Assembies in Azure pipeline

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, pipeline, microsoft-fakes

**introduction:**

I have a project in C# that has also related Unit Tests project. It uses Microsoft's Unit Test framework as well as its technology to creates Fakes. It works well locally - I am able to build project and run unit tests.

**problem:**

Now I try to add pipeline on dev.azure.com and I am getting an warnings like:

`Primary reference "___.Fakes". ##[warning]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2352,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "___.Fakes". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.`

and errors like:

`##[error]___\___Tests\___Tests.cs(9,43): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Fakes' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

etc.

**what I have already done:**

- I put `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll` as Solution item and reference it manually browsing as read that these dlls are not available in NuGETs.
- I have turned off the IntelliTrace in MSBuild Arguments `/p:EnableIntelliTrace=false`

**question**

- How to make this pipeline working? So **how to create Fakes assemblies during pipeline build on Azure?**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explicitly referencing certain DLLs, try using NuGet packages. This can help guarantee that all required dependencies are resolved appropriately during the build process. You stated manually referencing `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"` and `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll."` And build your project locally and then Push it in Azure DevOps repository. These should be available through NuGet packages in most cases.

***Make sure you check your csproj files and all the references are correctly added there:-***

[image]

Make sure you refer this [**Unit Test Run tutorial**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/run-quality-tests-build-pipeline/4-add-unit-tests) to run your Unit Tests successfully in Azure DevOps pipeline:-

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/<test-files-dlls>'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run unit tests - $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Test Run was successful in Azure Test Plan tab like below:-**

[image]